# Next.js/React: Dark mode class not applied until a change is made locally

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/dark-mode-in-react-an-in-depth-guide/) (using [react-toggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toggle)) to implement a dark mode toggle in my project. The toggle currently works as intended, save for one instance: on initial page load.

If the browser currently has `prefers-color-scheme: dark`, the dark mode toggle will not have the `react-toggle--checked` class until I make a change locally in VSCode and hit save. Only afterwards will the this class be applied.

Before hitting save:
[image]

After saving:
[image: react-toggle--checked is applied]

I'm not sure why this is happening. The initial `isDark` value is true, so presumably the Toggle's `checked` value is true, and thus should have the `react-toggle--checked` class applied. Why would making a local change in my editor and then saving affect whether or not this class is applied?

I'm using Next.js and React.

*useColorScheme.js*

```
import { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'
import createPersistedState from 'use-persisted-state'

const useColorSchemeState = createPersistedState('colorScheme')

export function useColorScheme() {
  const systemPrefersDark = useMediaQuery(
    {
      query: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
    },
    undefined,
  );

  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useColorSchemeState()

  const value = useMemo(() => isDark === undefined ? !!systemPrefersDark : isDark,
    [isDark, systemPrefersDark])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      document.body.classList.add('dark')
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('dark')
    }
  }, [value])

  return {
    isDark: value,
    setIsDark
  }
}
```

*ColorSchemeToggle.js*

```
import Toggle from 'react-toggle'
import { useColorScheme } from './useColorScheme'

// Styles
import 'react-toggle/style.css'

const ColorSchemeToggle = () => {
    const { isDark, setIsDark } = useColorScheme()

    return (
        <Toggle
            checked={isDark}
            onChange={({ target }) => setIsDark(target.checked)}
            aria-label='Dark mode toggle'
            className={`dark-mode-toggle`}
        />
    )
}

export default ColorSchemeToggle
```

Comment: Are you checking these changes in dev or prod mode? Also, would be helpful to post it in codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: @Ramakay I'm checking these changes in dev mode, but when I build and run the class is still not being applied properly (`react-toggle--checked` is not applied on page load).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `usepersistedstate` uses localstorage by default

https://github.com/donavon/use-persisted-state

> use-persisted-state is not a hook itself, but is a factory that accepts a storage key and an optional storage provider (default = localStorage) and returns a hook that you can use as a direct replacement for useState.